# imageio.ffmpeg.download() has been deprecated. So can anybody tell me what is the replacement of this library?

Tags: python

Actually I am trying to convert pdf to audio and video file converter.
So I have been stuck in the given runtime error:

imageio.ffmpeg.download() has been deprecated. So can anybody tell me what is the replacement of this library?
And how to proceed further?

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
sudo pip3 install imageio==2.4.1
```

with anaconda:

```
conda install imageio=2.4.1
```